# SQL Server schema naming convention

Tags: sql-server, schema, naming-conventions

Are there any industry standard naming conventions for naming schemas in SQL Server?

Unfortunately a few reserved words such as admin describe my planned schemas the most clearly. To get around this I have been debating on making the schema names plural, but in a way that doesn't make sense, and will cause an issue with the Products.Products schema and table.

So I was wondering if there was any clear convention that Microsoft or the industry uses?

Comment: Since this would be extremely dependent on the underlying data, your design and requirements, no. You'll find best practices of not using reserved words but what you name it would be pretty much up to the creator. Personally, keep it clear and simple IMHO.

Comment: one idea : put the word "schema" as a suffix.  AdminSchema, LookupSchema, etc ,etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found this reference for **SQL Server Name Conventions**

[SQL Server Name Convention and T-SQL Programming Style](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SQL%20Server%20Name%20Convention%20and%20T-SQL%20Programming%20Style.md)

It says to use lowercase and no plurals in schemas

[image]

Comment: This is just someone's opinion of some naming conventions (albeit quite comprehensive) rather than anything official though isn't it? I'm not sold on uppercase for database name and don't think this can be described as industry standard.